# Change in SEO Ranking

Tags: seo, google-search

There are two companies **A** and **B**. They have a joint venture called **AB Group**. Company **A** does more news and social media publishing when compared to company **AB Group** and is high up on the SEO rankings. When I search content related to company **A**, currently the 4th/5th link on `google` are always related to **AB Group**. Now Company **A** is selling its stake in **AB Group** and they have to remove everything related to company **A** from its assets(branding, domains etc) and company **A** is completely separating itself from **AB Group**.

What I want to know is when we search anything related company **A**, can we push the content related to **AB Group** down further so that it comes on way back on search engine search results? Is this possible?

In general, how do you think the SEO rankings will play out over time as I am not sure what will happen with **AB Group** in the future.

**EDIT:**

sorry for not being clear about the websites part....A and B are separate entities with their own sites. AB is a joint venture between A and B which is independent of A and B and has its own site and A and B has equal stake in AB. Now A wants to come out of the business of AB but selling its part of the stake to a third party (mostly a competitor) thus removing its name/branding from AB completely. Currently when I search for A, I get links for AB on the first page itself which A wants to avoid in the future. Say AB becomes BC and when searching for A, the links for AB should be way back in the search results as now AB is BC.

Comment: Was A previously linking or redirecting to AB? if so, you may lose a lot of the authority and links that passed to AB. Simply adding more content to counter weight the lost content won't balance things as you would expect. Google cares little for content these days, despite what Google says, domain authority, age and links is the most weight factors.  However, new content may attach new visitors, new chances and so forth, so new content should never be avoided, just don't expect it to correct your rankings drop.

Comment: @SimonHayter there is no linking between A and AB, both are completely independent but they share "A" in the names thus the search results...so basically what we can do is post new content/links which will be hopefully picked up by the search engine crawler over time and pushing the AB related links/content back in the search results...am I correct? (I don't have much knowledge about SEO :D)

Comment: I'm confused... from what I've read... two sites have merged... now they are split... A is now independent, but you haven't told us who keeps the AB domain, is A getting a new domain, old domain or what? less of the history, more of what's now.

Comment: So there's three sites, A, B and C... C being A&B yes? Now... they split its back to A and B, or A and C?

Comment: @SimonHayter I have edited the question